# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, salesforcedx, developer

I have ran my visualforce page in varacode and got flaws and I have fixed those with some changes but after that
in console I'm getting an errror called "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'"

```
    Flaw Code in VF Page :
    ----------------------
    var BAUDate = new Date({!BAUDateYear}, {!BAUDateMonth - 1}, 1); 

    Changed like this 
    ------------------
    var BAUDateYear = parseInt("{!JSENCODE(Text(BAUDateYear))}");
    var BAUDateMonth = parseInt("{!JSENCODE(Text(BAUDateMonth))}");
    var BAUDate = new Date(BAUDateYear, {BAUDateMonth - 1}, 1);

    after changing the code like above flaws fixed but I'm getting an errror called "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'"

    Can anyone please help how to  fix this issue 

    Regards,
    Sathwik
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `BAUDate` like below(remove curly braces around `BAUDateMonth`):

```
var BAUDate = new Date(BAUDateYear, BAUDateMonth - 1, 1);
```

Curly braces are for variables from Apex Controller/Extension.